# iOS : Zxing QR Code Reader in ipad not working in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, qr-code, zxing, landscape

I am working on a **landscape only** iPad app and trying to integrate [Zxing QR Code Scanner library](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) to the project. I am able to successfully integrate the library, and run without any compiler errors.

### Issues

1. Even though my application is landscape, the Zxing camera view is
   showing as portrait.
2. I am not able to scan using the library. I don't know whether camera
   layer showing in different orientation is the reason for it.

### My project setup

1. iPad landscape only application
2. target sdk        : **iOS 6.1**
3. deployment target : **iOS 6.0 or above**
4. zxing version     : **2.1**
5. testing on        : **iPad 2, iOS 6.1**

### My code

Well, code is simple, I am just calling `ZxingWidgetController` from my `HomeViewController` and implemented the delegate methods.. Delegates never getting fired.

#### HomeViewController.h

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<ZXingDelegate>{
}
@end
```

#### HomeViewController.m

```
-(void) openCameraScanner{
    ZXingWidgetController *ctrller       =   [[ZXingWidgetController alloc] 
                              initWithDelegate:self showCancel:YES OneDMode:NO];
    ctrller.delegate                     = self;
    [self presentViewController:ctrller animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController *)controller 
                             didScanResult:(NSString *)reslt{
    [self showDismissiveAlertWithMessage:[NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"qr code read is : %@ ", reslt]];
}

- (void)zxingControllerDidCancel:(ZXingWidgetController *)controller{
    [self showDismissiveAlertWithMessage:@"Failed to read qr code"];
}
```

Well, if my question is not clear enough, this is a scaled down version of my landscape app with a portrait looking Zxing..

[image]

Comment: Nope, I have already used Zxing in different projects and it worked well.. Never looked for any other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget was never really designed for rotation and I'm not quite sure what it does. It's possible zxing is getting a distorted/badly cropped stream of images from AVFF because of the rotation. Handling all the different orientations is fairly error-prone when dealing with AVFF.

There is another interface to zxing for iOS/OS X in the objc directory. It's much lower level (the CALayer level). This makes integrating it more work but also makes handling rotations (more) feasible. It doesn't do anything magic for rotations: you still have to place and transform layers yourself and that is fundamentally somewhat tricky.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in ZXingWidgetController.m when viewDidAppear

```
float iDegree = 90.0f;
  CATransform3D transform =  CATransform3DMakeRotation(iDegree, 0, 0, 1.0);
    self.prevLayer.transform =transform;
    self.prevLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024, 768);
```